# Is there a way to implicitly convert an enum class to std::byte?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following function:

```
uint_fast32_t write(const std::vector<std::byte>& bytes_to_write) const
{
    ...
}
```

And I want to call it with variable number of `std::byte`s:

```
std::byte low_byte { 0 };
std::byte hi_byte{ GPIO_PINS::GPIOH0 | GPIO_PINS::GPIOH3 };

write({
    INST::SET_LOW,
    low_byte,
    0xFB,
    INST::SET_HI,
    hi_byte,
    0xFF
    });
```

(`INST` and `GPIO_PINS` are `enum class : byte` - mind the difference between `byte` (actually `unsigned char`) and `std::byte`, in this regard..)

But that won't compile. I have to adjust the call as follows:

```
write({
    std::byte(INST::SET_LOW),
    low_byte,
    std::byte(0xFB),
    std::byte(INST::SET_HI),
    hi_byte,
    std::byte(0xFF)
    });
```

My question is whether there is a way to eliminate the need for that `std::byte` constructors (or `static_cast`)?

Maybe some implicit operator overriding or the like?

Comment: This whole construct with passing sequence of separate bytes in constructor of temporary vector seems to be rather suspicious. Why won't you use some kind of meaningful structure or builder that would accept values like `INST::SET_LOW` directly?

Comment: @VTT, why does it look suspicious? I want to pass variable number of bytes. What do you mean by "meaningful structure or builder"?

Comment: Because the bytes passed have no meaning.

Answer (score 6):

"Is there a way to implicitly convert an enum class to std::byte?" - No.

Type safe enumerations do not allow implicit conversions to other types. You *must* use a cast.

See also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

Comment: Could you elaborate or transform your answer to a comment? As is, it really looks like an opinion.

Comment: @YSC How is "No (it cannot be done)" look like an opinion? If it cant be done, it cant be done that looks like a fact to me.

Comment: @YSC it is not an opinion, it is a fact, both semantically and technically.

Comment: @YSC I elaborated a bit, but I still think "No" is an acceptable answer since that's the fact. "No. You cannot do that". It's not opinion. It's fact. Stated as short and simple as possible.

Comment: A statement without explanation or a source looks an opinion to me. It can be right, it can be wrong. Example: "unicorns exist". The answer has been fixed now :) +1

Comment: @SergeyA There is an inherent difference between what something *is*  and what something *looks like*. For you, for me, as we know from experience Jesper is right, this is a fact. For someone who doesn't (like OP), this could be both. [_"A fact is something that can be checked and backed up with evidence."_](http://www.bbc.co.uk/skillswise/factsheet/en06opin-l1-f-what-is-fact-and-opinion). Since Jesper statement _can_ be backed up by evidence, I asked him to do so. What's wrong in that?

Comment: @YSC For the record; *I* don't think there is anything *wrong* in you asking me to elaborate. I think it was *unnecessary*, but that's not the same as *wrong*. And I *did* elaborate as you asked.

Comment: @YSC: "*Since Jesper statement can be backed up by evidence, I asked him to do so.*" No, you didn't. You asked "Could you elaborate or transform your answer to a comment?" If you wanted him to cite the standard or otherwise provide evidence, you should have asked for that specifically. You said "elaborate", which could really mean anything.

Comment: So much dramaaaaaaa. Nice answer Jesper. I'm outa here.

Answer (score 3):

The whole purpose of an `enum class` is to not be implicitly convertible to its underlying type (and to scope its values).  If implicit conversion is what you need then you need to fall back to using a plain `enum`, or write the casts yourself.

You can make an implicitly convertible `enum` that acts like an `enum class` by putting a regular `enum` into a `namespace`.  That way its values are scoped to the namespace, but you get the implicit conversion a regular enum offers.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do so. User-defined implicit conversions must be through constructors or conversion operators. But both constructors and conversion operators are required to be class members, which enums, of course, cannot have.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to define conversion operator for `enum class`.

However to achive your goal you can make write function generic to make it possible to pass arguments of different types:

```
template <typename Enum>
uint32_t write(Enum e)
{
    static_assert(std::is_enum<Enum>::value && sizeof(e) == 1, "");
    // write enum
}

uint32_t write(std::byte b)
{
    // write enum
}

template <typename ...Args>
uint32_t write(Args... args)
{
    return (write(args) + ...);
}
```

(I assume that function return number of bytes being written so use `+` as fold operator)

Comment: I can't combine both `INST` enum values, numeric values and `std::byte` this way: the `uint32_t write(Args... args)` function expects the values to be of the same type. I mean I can't call: `write(INST::SET_LOW, low_byte /* of type std::byte*/, 0xFB)` because input variables are of different types.

Comment: @Tar, why not? `Args` can be a list of different types. Here is a compilable example: https://godbolt.org/z/qM1A6G